# Bootstrap datetime picker remove meridian am/pm

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smalot-datetimepicker

I'm using asp.net MVC `TextBoxFor` to bind bootstrap-datetimepicker. It's working fine with simple input type text box.

But when I'm binding it with mvc textbox helper it's showing wrong year like `'31/10/1899 00:00'`

Then I got the solution somewhere to fix that.

```js
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii:00P",
    autoclose: true
});
```

It's working fine, but now It's adding meridians at the very end like AM/PM. I need to remove those AM/PM.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the P at the end of your foramt variable see below

```
format: "dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii:00",
```

Comment: I tried this but then as I mentioned above it's changing the year to December 1899.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            showMeridian:false
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

As two previous answers said, to remove meridian you can combine both `format` and `showMeridian` usage:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ 
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii:00",
    autoclose: true,
    showMeridian: false
});
```

However, there is a glitch when datepicker lost its focus without selecting anything or making incomplete selections, it reverts date back to December 31, 1899 (reproduced in [this example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/unllb2)). I managed to check `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` file and found `parseDate` function causing this behavior:

```
parseDate: function (date, format, language, type, timezone) {
    var parts = date && date.toString().match(this.nonpunctuation) || [],
        // this line below represents December 31, 1899 (try using console.log)
        date = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
        // -- skipped for brevity --
    val, filtered, part;
    // -- skipped for brevity --
}
```

A little tweak is possible by changing `date` assignment into current date:

```
parseDate: function (date, format, language, type, timezone) {
    var parts = date && date.toString().match(this.nonpunctuation) || [],
        date = new Date(),
        // -- skipped for brevity --
    val, filtered, part;
    // -- skipped for brevity --
}
```

Note: This tweak only available for non-CDN script (installed through NuGet package or manually placed in `Scripts` folder).

Related issues:

[Issue #494: Date set to '31 Dec 1899 00:00' when focus lost without selecting date](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/494)

[Issue #153](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/pull/153)